# Searching using SQL Server Full Text Index support 'or not' operation

Tags: full-text-search, sql-server-2016

Is there a way to support Boolean expression like

```
(x and y) or (not z)
```

in full text index search?

I am using SQL Server 2016.

I have read this article: [CONTAINS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql)

I see that 'or not' is not supported. Any help?

Comment: This seems kind of hacky and might not work, but what about doing something like `(X and Y) OR (1 and not Z)`. Since `NOT` can only appear after `AND`, you add another condition that will always be true before the `AND NOT`.

Comment: Just curious if you had tried the hack suggested by `digital.aaron`. Did it work?

Comment: @andrews it did not work but from the first sight i thought that it was a good  answer